# File permissions changing on save ( using root )

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, root, file-permissions

Using a fresh installation of CENTOS 6.2, when I connect to the server ( SFTP mount with nautilus ) and edit files, no matter what permission the file had before, it is reset to 700, read+write+execute only for the owner. 
When SSHing directly into the machine and editing files on the command line - no permissions are changed.

The files I am editing are website scripts sitting in my Apache folders.

Why is this behavior happening? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your FTP client might be "downloading and reuploading" your files when you edit them. Change your umask if you want different permissions, or use SSH and a proper editor if you want to keep the permissions...